# How to check (in the formula directly) if entry already calculated in previous rows (to avoid duplicates entries)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using this kind of datafile

```
A    | B          | C          | D
1010 | 18/06/2020 | 20/06/2020 | 3
1010 | 18/06/2020 | 20/06/2020 | 3
1010 | 18/06/2020 | 20/06/2020 | 3
1011 | 20/06/2020 | 21/06/2020 | 2
1032 | 01/07/2020 | 05/07/2020 | 4
1032 | 01/07/2020 | 05/07/2020 | 4
```

`Column D` is the difference in days. However I would like to calculate it only one time (on the first occurence) by `id` (`Column A`).

So expected result is

```
A    | B          | C          | D
1010 | 18/06/2020 | 20/06/2020 | 3
1010 | 18/06/2020 | 20/06/2020 |
1032 | 01/07/2020 | 05/07/2020 | 4 
1011 | 20/06/2020 | 21/06/2020 | 2
1010 | 18/06/2020 | 20/06/2020 | 
1032 | 01/07/2020 | 05/07/2020 |
```

Do you know if it is possible to do it ?

Thank you,

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are calculating the no of days between the dates as what you've posted seems inconsistent.

In this formula I've simply subtracted the date in column B from the date in column C.

If you are using some other calculation replace `C2-B2` in the formula.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1, C2-B2,"")
```

Comment: Thank you for your commen. It is because I'm using NETWORKDAYS but don't worry even if it not correct it is not important for the moment. The main  thing for me is to avoid duplicates else average will be wrong. `COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1` will avoid duplicates ?* Because if i'm using this, it will be blank for all rows with a `count of id > 1.

Comment: Yes, that part of the formula will avoid duplicates.